# Switching between tabs hosted inside a TabActivity, without finishing child activites

Tags: android, tabs

I have a three tab layout which contains three forms. 
I want to switch between tabs and when I move to tab two from tab one after filling the form, and when I navigate back to tab one, I want to display the previously filled content.
How can I achieve this?

Any suggestions. 
Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your code? You can store the details in `onPause()` and retrieve it when you get back to that activity.

Comment: Hey Aniruddha, I have created something similar to this.
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/

Comment: Similar to what? What are you trying to say?

Comment: Three tabs. I used the link as a reference to create three tab layout. Actually I don't want to display details. I want tab one to remain as it was when I come back.\

Comment: you can save the state and restore it see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android)

Comment: @Droidy do you have edittexts in first tab? If you need help you have to post your code.

Comment: Thank you SMR. It's worthy.

Comment: @Aniruddha Yeah. There are several edittexts. Not only on the first tabs, but also on the second tab too. I just passed a bean through tab activities and by checking null of the bean, I filled those edittexts, yet don't know the efficiency though. Anyway, thank you.